# What is the exact need of various data members of a typescript class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular 2 project with the following classes.

**Bike.list.service.ts class**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, HttpModule,Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Bike} from './bike.model';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class BikeService {
  private _Url = 'https://feeds.bikesharetoronto.com/stations/stations.json';

  constructor(private _http:Http) { }

  getStations(): Observable<Bike[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._Url)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    console.log(body);
    return body.stationBeanList || { };
  }

  private handleError (error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

**Bike.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Bike} from './bike.model';
import {BikeService} from './bike.list.service';

@Component( {
  selector:'bike-stations',
  templateUrl:'../app/bike/bike-list.view.html',
  providers:[BikeService]
})

export class BikeComponent implements OnInit {

  stations:Bike[];
  errorMessage:any;
  mode = 'Observable';

  constructor(private _bikeListService: BikeService) {
    this.stations=[];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getStations();
  }

  getStations() {
    this._bikeListService.getStations().subscribe(
      (stations: any) => this.stations = stations,
      (error: any) => this.errorMessage = error
    );
  }
}
```

**Bike.model.ts**

```
export class  Bike{

  private id:number;
  private stationName:string;
  private availableDocks:number;
  private totalDocks:number;
  private latitude:number;
  private longitude:number;
  private statusValue:number;
  private statusKey:number;
  private status:string;
  private availableBikes:number;
  private stAddress1:string;
  private stAddress2:string;
  private city:string;
  private postalCode:string;
  private location:string;
  private altitude:string;
  private testStation:boolean;
  private lastCommunicationTime:Date;
  private is_renting:boolean;
  private landMark:string;

  constructor(bike_info: Array<any>){

  this.id=bike_info['id'];
    this.stationName=bike_info['stationName'];
    this.availableDocks=bike_info['availableDocks'];
    this.totalDocks=bike_info['totalDocks'];
    this.latitude=bike_info['latitude'];
    this.longitude=bike_info['longitude'];
    this.statusValue=bike_info['statusValue'];
    this.statusKey=bike_info['statusKey'];
    this.status=bike_info['status'];
    this.availableBikes=bike_info['availableBikes'];
    this.stAddress1=bike_info['stAddress1'];
    this.stAddress2=bike_info['stAddress2'];
    this.city=bike_info['city'];
    this.postalCode=bike_info['postalCode'];
    this.location=bike_info['location'];
    this.altitude=bike_info['altitude'];
    this.testStation=bike_info['testStation'];
    this.lastCommunicationTime=bike_info['lastCommunicationTime'];
    this.is_renting=bike_info['is_renting'];
    this.landMark=bike_info['landMark'];
  }
}
```

**bike-list.html**

```html
<div>
  <h1>Stations List...</h1>

  <div *ngFor="let station of stations">
    <td>
      <div>Id: {{station.id}}</div>
      <div>Station Name: {{station.stationName}}</div>
      <div>availableDocks: {{station.availableDocks}} </div>
      <div>totalDocks: {{station.totalDocks}} </div>
      <div>latitude: {{station.latitude}} </div>
      <div>longitude: {{station.longitude}} </div>
      <div>statusValue: {{station.statusValue}} </div>
      <div>statusKey: {{station.statusKey}} </div>
      <div>status: {{station.status}} </div>
      <div>availableBikes: {{station.availableBikes}} </div>
      <div>stAddress1: {{station.stAddress1}} </div>
      <div>stAddress2: {{station.stAddress2}} </div>
      <div>city: {{station.city}} </div>
      <div>postalCode: {{station.postalCode}} </div>
      <div>location: {{station.location}} </div>
      <div>altitude: {{station.altitude}} </div>
      <div>testStation: {{station.testStation}} </div>
      <div>lastCommunicationTime: {{station.lastCommunicationTime}} </div>
      <div>is_renting: {{station.is_renting}} </div>
      <div>landMark: {{station.landMark}} </div>
    </td>
    <br><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is- When the observable returns the data, it is getting assigned to Bike[] class and 'stations'(type is Bike[]) declared in Bikecomponent class gets the JSON data for all the data members of the Hero class.

However, if I delete some data members from Bike class, it doesn't affect the 'stations'(of type Bike[]) array and it still prints all the attributes specified in HTML.

So what is the need of declaring those many numbers of data members in the Bike model class? Can anyone give me explanation?

Comment: When you said Hero model class, are you referring to Bike model class, just to clarify?

Comment: @Alcruz Yes. I'm sorry

Comment: What are you asking about? TypeScript was created to add static typing to JavaScript, in order to provide better code analysis, better compile-time errors, etc.. If you don't want to type anything, don't use types and mark everything with the `any` type.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan My question is- What is the benefit a Typescript class when JSON data is not caring about about the class structure? Also, I can write any properties to a class since there is no matching or assigning by the JSON returned.

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/ The same reason you use TypeScript for anything. If you write an app that uses JSON, and the JSON structure changes, don't you think you'd need to update your app anyway? This just gives you a more orderly way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular scenario classes in typescript allow you to type your json, that can have some benefits, one is that you can see the types of your properties when you are coding and that can save you from mistakes, also clarify a little bit the code. As you spotted at runtime typescript doesn't care about the structure of your json, so anyway it will assign whatever data comes in regardless of whatever type you have and that is the expected behavior because at the end typescript is javascript at runtime.

But some of typescript benefits comes when you are coding or transpiling, thus I recommend that you look of the benefits at those steps.

If you think those benefits aren't strong enough to force you to code on typescript then you can try es6.

Comment: What is the need when JSON data is not caring about about the class structure? Also, I can write any properties to a class since there is no matching or assigning by the JSON returned.